# backbone vs extjs(core + xtemplate + store)?

Tags: extjs, backbone.js

I had use extjs from 2.2 to 4.1

now I found backbonejs, it's so lightweight.

I wonder are they do the same job as the table descript below?

I mean using extjs-core + dataview + xtemplate + store (from ext3, you can package what you want) , not using the whole extjs.

```
| BackBone   | ExtJS       |
|:-----------|------------:|
| underscore | ext-core    |  
| model      | model       |  
| collection | store       |  
| event      | event       |
| router     | ??          |
| view       | DataView + XTemplate|
| MIT        | GPLv3       |
```

Comment: Suits your need :). ExtJs is strict on the styling part and add's all the nonsense to the html so that it can work great dynamically. With backbone you got freedom to do almost anything you wish for. Rather than trying to fork through the api and customize I would use Backbonejs for it's simplicity and ease of implementation. Again it is hard to say what you require out of the two one is a library another a component

Comment: not gonna get a straight answer here. mainly because one is not 'better' than the other in any sense of the word, they are different and alike in many ways. if you need to, choose the one that best fits your skill set.